# How to select from multiple tables using ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select from multiple tables, but my result is only giving me the result for the table I'm running the query from.

```
c=Performance.with_category.category_joiner.joins(:category).merge(Category.product_in('C4')).distinct
```

my with_category scope

```
scope :with_category, -> {select('performance.*, category.*')}
```

when I run `c.first` I get all my Performance values but not my category values

The reason I can't run `c.first.category` is because it reruns sql, but there are multiple columns that need to be joined on (date, code, etc), so I need a way to return both the category and performance values from the original sql.

Comment: You have several syntax errors in your code (an extra `)` in the first; a missing `'` in the second). Please paste your actual code.

Comment: @Jordan I can't post my actual code due to NDA (I can't display the db tables or associations)

Comment: You need to use `includes` instead of `joins`. Includes eager loads the data while joins is used to load data meeting criteria.

Comment: @CWitty includes doesn't work due to the multiple constraints required to link the tables together

Comment: You can use `includes` with `where` to filter based on constraints, checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: @CWitty This doesn't seem to work for some reason.  When I run the generated sql through a sql editor I get a valid response.  When I run it through Ruby, it doesn't work.  In my SQL editor, i get `T0_R94 = TVLAX T1_R0 5/30/2014` but when i do `Performance.first.category` I get `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`